# Default form field is empty after post in Django

Tags: django

Model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.datetime.now)
    text = models.TextField()
```

Form:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
```

In template I have only "text" field. When I click on submit button, QueryDict in form.data contains only text, despite the default value for date field. How to set default value properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

I figured that `default=datetime.date.now` behaved like `auto_now_add=True` because you mentioned that your template only contains the `text` field.

It turns out your situation is not handled any differently and you must display the `date` field in your form.

If you want to ignore it, you can override the `ModelForm.save` method to set the date yourself, or add it in your model `save()` definition.

You should look into the `auto_now_add=True` parameter in model field definitions which automatically adds this behavior of setting a date field to `datetime.datetime.now()` upon the first save.

```
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: "Saving this model / modelform will automatically populate the default in the instance / database." But form.is_valid() returns False and error message is "this field is required"

Comment: Ah, I guess `default=` doesn't do that. `auto_now_add` does the form exclusion behavior. I figured it was behaving the same because you said you "only have text field". In this case, you are simply not displaying the `form.date` field, which is populated with a default value.

Answer (score 0):

You should write

```
default = datetime.datetime.now()
```

with parentheses to call function ang get datetime. There is **auto_now** field to do this in better way. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield

These is another way to provide initial data from view:

`form = CommentForm( initial = { 'date': datetime.datetime.now(), 'text': u'', }`

Read more on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#initial